# Sobolev inequality with holes

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, differential-inequalities

Classical Sobolev  inequality says, $n\geq 3$, we have
\begin{equation}
        \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|u|^{2 n /(n-2)}\right)^{(n-2) /(2 n) } \leq C(n)\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|\nabla u|^{2}\right)^{1 / 2}\quad \text{for all}\,u\in D^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^n).
        \end{equation}
for some constant $C(n)$ depends on $n$. Here the space $D^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^n)=\{u\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^n):|\nabla u|\in L^{2 n /(n-2)}(\mathbb{R}^n)\}$.

My question is whether it is ture we have the Sobolev type inequality
\begin{equation}
        \left(\int_{\Omega}|u|^{2 n /(n-2)}\right)^{(n-2) /(2 n) } \leq C_{1}(n,\Omega)\left(\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^{2}\right)^{1 / 2},
        \end{equation}
with $\Omega=\mathbb{R}^n\backslash B_1(0)$, $u\in E=\{u \in L^{2n /(n-2)}(\Omega):|\nabla u|\in L^{2}(\Omega)\}$, $C_{1}(n,\Omega)$ is a constant only depends on $n$ and $\Omega$.

Comment: It is useful to recall the definition of the space $D^{1,2}$ here.

Comment: In the specific case: since $B_1(0)$ is convex, you can copy over Nirenberg's 1959 proof (the one integrating over rectangles) with almost zero change.

Comment: @WillieWong Could you be more precise: which paper and which result are you referring to?

Comment: @giorgio-metafune I believe he refers to Lecture II of *Louis Nirenberg. "[On elliptic partial differential equations](http://www.numdam.org/item/ASNSP_1959_3_13_2_115_0.pdf)." Annali della Scuola Normale Superiore di Pisa-Scienze Fisiche e Matematiche 13, no. 2 (1959): 115-162.*

Comment: There is also a recent rewriting *Alberto Fiorenza, Maria Rosaria Formica, Tomáš G. Roskovec, and Filip Soudský. "[Detailed proof of classical Gagliardo–Nirenberg interpolation inequality with historical remarks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.04281)" Zeitschrift für Analysis und ihre Anwendungen 40, no. 2 (2021): 217-236* which is very helpful.

Comment: @cs89 thanks, that is the one I am thinking of.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are looking for the extreme case of a Gagliardo-Nirenberg interpolation inequality, in the case of an **exterior domain** (that is, an unbounded domain with compact boundary). Such inequalities are derived for example in the following paper:

> Francesca Crispo and Paolo Maremonti. "[An interpolation inequality in exterior domains.](http://www.numdam.org/item/RSMUP_2004__112__11_0.pdf)" Rendiconti del Seminario Matematico della Università di Padova 112 (2004): 11-39.

This paper focuses on the case where no vanishing condition is imposed on $\partial\Omega$.

The case you mention follows from Theorem 2.1 with $m=1$, $p=2$, $k=0$, $r = \frac{2n}{n-2}$. Since $n\geq 3$, beware that you are in the "particular case" ($k = 0$ and $m p < n$) which requires the additionnal assumption that $w$ tends to 0 at infinity, or that $w \in L^{q'}$ for some $q'<\infty$ (which is your case with $q' = 2$).